# Why won't my tomcat in my local host run properly in Eclipse?

Tags: java, debugging, tomcat, servlets

I'm trying to make my page allow users to upload files onto their computers. Connecting `index.html` and `HelloServlet.java` is what I'm struggling with.  My `Tomcat` works fine because I'm getting `errors` in `Terminal` which's good because it shows it's connecting to my project.

I just can't see how this isn't working.  When I hit run, I want the `index.html` page to show up in one of the `Eclipse` tabs allowing me to upload files to my computer.  How can I fix this?

Every time I hit `run` in `Eclipse` I get these `errors` in `Terminal` ([pic of error in Eclipse)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pb3zB.png):

```
08-Oct-2017 16:00:01.872 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load Initialization processed in 999 ms
08-Oct-2017 16:00:01.979 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal Starting service [Catalina]
08-Oct-2017 16:00:01.980 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.23
08-Oct-2017 16:00:01.993 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [/Applications/tomcat/webapps/docs]
08-Oct-2017 16:00:02.609 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [/Applications/tomcat/webapps/docs] has finished in [615] ms
08-Oct-2017 16:00:02.610 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [/Applications/tomcat/webapps/examples]
08-Oct-2017 16:00:03.130 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [/Applications/tomcat/webapps/examples] has finished in [520] ms
08-Oct-2017 16:00:03.131 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [/Applications/tomcat/webapps/hello]
08-Oct-2017 16:00:03.189 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [/Applications/tomcat/webapps/hello] has finished in [58] ms
08-Oct-2017 16:00:03.189 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [/Applications/tomcat/webapps/host-manager]
08-Oct-2017 16:00:03.232 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [/Applications/tomcat/webapps/host-manager] has finished in [43] ms
08-Oct-2017 16:00:03.233 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [/Applications/tomcat/webapps/manager]
08-Oct-2017 16:00:03.271 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [/Applications/tomcat/webapps/manager] has finished in [38] ms
08-Oct-2017 16:00:03.272 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [/Applications/tomcat/webapps/ROOT]
08-Oct-2017 16:00:03.318 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [/Applications/tomcat/webapps/ROOT] has finished in [45] ms
08-Oct-2017 16:00:03.322 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
08-Oct-2017 16:00:03.330 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in 1457 ms
09-Oct-2017 07:40:36.569 WARNING [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.await StandardServer.await: Invalid command 'GET /FileUploadServlet/index.html HTTP/1.1' received
09-Oct-2017 07:40:36.674 WARNING [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.await StandardServer.await: Invalid command 'GET /FileUploadServlet/index.html HTTP/1.1' received
09-Oct-2017 07:40:36.779 WARNING [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.await StandardServer.await: Invalid command 'GET /FileUploadServlet/index.html HTTP/1.1' received
09-Oct-2017 07:40:57.556 WARNING [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.await StandardServer.await: Invalid command 'GET /FileUploadServlet/index.html HTTP/1.1' received
```

Here's `index.html`:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<form action="FileUploadServlet" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
Select File to Upload:<input type="file" name="fileName">
<br>
<input type="submit" value="Upload">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Here's `FileUploadServlet.java`:

```
package net.techsuite.SIPPA_HealthTech;
//package com.journaldev.servlet;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.MultipartConfig;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.Part;

@WebServlet("/FileUploadServlet")
@MultipartConfig(fileSizeThreshold=1024*1024*10,    // 10 MB 
                 maxFileSize=1024*1024*50,          // 50 MB
                 maxRequestSize=1024*1024*100)      // 100 MB
public class FileUploadServlet extends HttpServlet {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 205242440643911308L;

    /**
     * Directory where uploaded files will be saved, its relative to
     * the web application directory.
     */
    private static final String UPLOAD_DIR = "uploads";

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // gets absolute path of the web application
        String applicationPath = request.getServletContext().getRealPath("");
        // constructs path of the directory to save uploaded file
        String uploadFilePath = applicationPath + File.separator + UPLOAD_DIR;

        // creates the save directory if it does not exists
        File fileSaveDir = new File(uploadFilePath);
        if (!fileSaveDir.exists()) {
            fileSaveDir.mkdirs();
        }
        System.out.println("Upload File Directory="+fileSaveDir.getAbsolutePath());

        String fileName = "";
        //Get all the parts from request and write it to the file on server
        for (Part part : request.getParts()) {
            fileName = getFileName(part);
            File file = new File(fileName);
            part.write(uploadFilePath + File.separator + file.getName());
        }
        writeToResponse(response, "File uploaded successfully to: " + uploadFilePath);

        request.setAttribute("message", "File uploaded successfully!");
        getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/response.jsp").forward(
                request, response);

    }

    /**
     * Utility method to get file name from HTTP header content-disposition
     */
    private String getFileName(Part part) {
        String contentDisp = part.getHeader("content-disposition");
        System.out.println("content-disposition header= "+contentDisp);
        String[] tokens = contentDisp.split(";");
        for (String token : tokens) {
            if (token.trim().startsWith("filename")) {
                return token.substring(token.indexOf("=") + 2, token.length()-1);
            }
        }
        return "";
    }


    private void writeToResponse(HttpServletResponse resp, String results) throws IOException {
        PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(resp.getOutputStream());
        resp.setContentType("text/plain");

        if (results.isEmpty()) {
            writer.write("No results found.");
        } else {
            writer.write(results);
        }
        writer.close();
    }   


}
```

Here's `web.xml` file in `WebContent` folder:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">
  <display-name>FileUploadServlet</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

Here's `server.xml` file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
  Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
  contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
  this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
  The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
  (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
  the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at

      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

  Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
  distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
  WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
  See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
  limitations under the License.
--><!-- Note:  A "Server" is not itself a "Container", so you may not
     define subcomponents such as "Valves" at this level.
     Documentation at /docs/config/server.html
 --><Server port="8005" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener"/>
  <!-- Security listener. Documentation at /docs/config/listeners.html
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityListener" />
  -->
  <!--APR library loader. Documentation at /docs/apr.html -->
  <Listener SSLEngine="on" className="org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener"/>
  <!-- Prevent memory leaks due to use of particular java/javax APIs-->
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JreMemoryLeakPreventionListener"/>
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.mbeans.GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener"/>
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.ThreadLocalLeakPreventionListener"/>

  <!-- Global JNDI resources
       Documentation at /docs/jndi-resources-howto.html
  -->
  <GlobalNamingResources>
    <!-- Editable user database that can also be used by
         UserDatabaseRealm to authenticate users
    -->
    <Resource auth="Container" description="User database that can be updated and saved" factory="org.apache.catalina.users.MemoryUserDatabaseFactory" name="UserDatabase" pathname="conf/tomcat-users.xml" type="org.apache.catalina.UserDatabase"/>
  </GlobalNamingResources>

  <!-- A "Service" is a collection of one or more "Connectors" that share
       a single "Container" Note:  A "Service" is not itself a "Container",
       so you may not define subcomponents such as "Valves" at this level.
       Documentation at /docs/config/service.html
   -->
  <Service name="Catalina">

    <!--The connectors can use a shared executor, you can define one or more named thread pools-->
    <!--
    <Executor name="tomcatThreadPool" namePrefix="catalina-exec-"
        maxThreads="150" minSpareThreads="4"/>
    -->


    <!-- A "Connector" represents an endpoint by which requests are received
         and responses are returned. Documentation at :
         Java HTTP Connector: /docs/config/http.html
         Java AJP  Connector: /docs/config/ajp.html
         APR (HTTP/AJP) Connector: /docs/apr.html
         Define a non-SSL/TLS HTTP/1.1 Connector on port 8080
    -->
    <Connector connectionTimeout="20000" port="8005" protocol="HTTP/1.1" redirectPort="8443"/>
    <!-- A "Connector" using the shared thread pool-->
    <!--
    <Connector executor="tomcatThreadPool"
               port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               redirectPort="8443" />
    -->
    <!-- Define a SSL/TLS HTTP/1.1 Connector on port 8443
         This connector uses the NIO implementation. The default
         SSLImplementation will depend on the presence of the APR/native
         library and the useOpenSSL attribute of the
         AprLifecycleListener.
         Either JSSE or OpenSSL style configuration may be used regardless of
         the SSLImplementation selected. JSSE style configuration is used below.
    -->
    <!--
    <Connector port="8443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
               maxThreads="150" SSLEnabled="true">
        <SSLHostConfig>
            <Certificate certificateKeystoreFile="conf/localhost-rsa.jks"
                         type="RSA" />
        </SSLHostConfig>
    </Connector>
    -->
    <!-- Define a SSL/TLS HTTP/1.1 Connector on port 8443 with HTTP/2
         This connector uses the APR/native implementation which always uses
         OpenSSL for TLS.
         Either JSSE or OpenSSL style configuration may be used. OpenSSL style
         configuration is used below.
    -->
    <!--
    <Connector port="8443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol"
               maxThreads="150" SSLEnabled="true" >
        <UpgradeProtocol className="org.apache.coyote.http2.Http2Protocol" />
        <SSLHostConfig>
            <Certificate certificateKeyFile="conf/localhost-rsa-key.pem"
                         certificateFile="conf/localhost-rsa-cert.pem"
                         certificateChainFile="conf/localhost-rsa-chain.pem"
                         type="RSA" />
        </SSLHostConfig>
    </Connector>
    -->

    <!-- Define an AJP 1.3 Connector on port 8009 -->
    <Connector port="8008" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443"/>


    <!-- An Engine represents the entry point (within Catalina) that processes
         every request.  The Engine implementation for Tomcat stand alone
         analyzes the HTTP headers included with the request, and passes them
         on to the appropriate Host (virtual host).
         Documentation at /docs/config/engine.html -->

    <!-- You should set jvmRoute to support load-balancing via AJP ie :
    <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost" jvmRoute="jvm1">
    -->
    <Engine defaultHost="localhost" name="Catalina">

      <!--For clustering, please take a look at documentation at:
          /docs/cluster-howto.html  (simple how to)
          /docs/config/cluster.html (reference documentation) -->
      <!--
      <Cluster className="org.apache.catalina.ha.tcp.SimpleTcpCluster"/>
      -->

      <!-- Use the LockOutRealm to prevent attempts to guess user passwords
           via a brute-force attack -->
      <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm">
        <!-- This Realm uses the UserDatabase configured in the global JNDI
             resources under the key "UserDatabase".  Any edits
             that are performed against this UserDatabase are immediately
             available for use by the Realm.  -->
        <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm" resourceName="UserDatabase"/>
      </Realm>

      <Host appBase="webapps" autoDeploy="true" name="localhost" unpackWARs="true">

        <!-- SingleSignOn valve, share authentication between web applications
             Documentation at: /docs/config/valve.html -->
        <!--
        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.authenticator.SingleSignOn" />
        -->

        <!-- Access log processes all example.
             Documentation at: /docs/config/valve.html
             Note: The pattern used is equivalent to using pattern="common" -->
        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs" pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" prefix="localhost_access_log" suffix=".txt"/>

      <Context docBase="FileUploadServlet" path="/FileUploadServlet" reloadable="true" source="org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:FileUploadServlet"/></Host>
    </Engine>
  </Service>
</Server>
```

Comment: Have you done the mapping in your deployment descriptor properly?

Comment: @robot_alien Not sure, how do I do that?  (nice name btw)

Comment: `@WebServlet("/FileUploadServlet").` / Do we still need mapping after that @robot_alien

Comment: Error anyway is not in servlet. Index page itself is not coming up as it looks from description. web.xml entry may not be needed in jee7

Comment: @robot_alien I have two `web.xml` files.  One in my `servers` folder and one inside `WebContent` folder.  The one I've just posted is inside `WebContent` folder.

Comment: @Optional I'm using `Eclipse Oxygen`.

Comment: It's not an issue with your app. Post your server.xml or check the admin port. Specify the admin port matching your url port that you get in error.

Comment: @Optional Posted server.xml file in my original post.

Comment: @obsolutemal Added the answer based on your server.xml info. Shutdown after change and retry.

Answer (score 0):

`<Server port="8005" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">` is the cause of error. You are calling index.html on a shutdown port.

That shall be different from below connector.

`<Connector connectionTimeout="20000" port="8005" protocol="HTTP/1.1" redirectPort="8443"/>`

Change that to e.g

`<Connector address="0.0.0.0" connectionTimeout="20000" port="8009" protocol="HTTP/1.1" redirectPort="8443"/>`

Also check if there are any port occupied by 8005 and see why? Kill the process if any.

Comment: Where can I find the proper address for my case?

Comment: it's just that both shall not be same. Just add 8009 and run to try. then your port will be 8009